# Help me understand the use of autant in this example

Tags: constructions

I understand the meaning of `autant`, however I do not understand how it applies in this sentence. Can you help me understand what it means?

```
Puisque j'étais déjà soupçonné de voler, autant le faire.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Autant* normally means "just as soon", "just as much", and by extension "equally good" or "with equal consequences". Thus, here it carries the meaning "might as well":

> Since I was already suspected of stealing, I might as well do it.